# Why do I need the execute permission to upload files via SFTP?

Tags: permissions, sftp

I have an directory with 664 permission so the owner and group should be able to read and write.

`drw-rw-r-- 2 sftpuser   sftpusers 4096 Aug  8 14:02 sftp`

But when I try to upload a file via sftp I get the following error:

```
Command:   put "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg" "Chrysanthemum.jpg"
Error:     /Data/sftp/Chrysanthemum.jpg: open for write: permission denied
```

After changing the permissions to 774 it works.

Why do I need the execute permission to write a file?